# Trivial surface integral over sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Determine the flux of the vector field $$\mathbf{A}=(x^2,2y,z)$$ through the sphere $|r|=R$. Use the parametrization $\mathbf{r} = R(\sin u \cos v,\sin u \sin v,\cos u)$.

Okay so this seems simple enough. We get $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}) = (R^2 \sin^2 u \cos^2 v, ...)$ and $d\mathbf{S}$ = $R^2 \sin u \: dudv\: \hat{e}_r$ where $u: 0 \to \pi, v: 0\to 2\pi$. This yields $$\iint_{r=R} \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{S} = \iint R^4 \sin^3 u \cos^2 v \:dudv = R^4 \dfrac{4\pi}{3}$$ which is wrong (answer is $4\pi R^3$). Can anyone spot my mistake(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d\mathbf S$ needs to be a vector element of surface area (i.e., $\mathbf n\,dS$). But, by the way, $dS = R^2\sin u\,du\,dv$. So you should have 
$$d\mathbf S = R^2\sin u\big(\sin u\cos v,\sin u\sin v,\cos u\big)du\,dv.$$
I'm actually not sure how you managed to get a scalar integral from what you were doing.

Comment: My post was riddled with mistakes as I had written off stuff from another exercise. It should be as I had intended now. What I used was $d\mathbf{S} = h_1h_2 du_1 du_2 \hat{e}_3$ which for spherical coordinates $\{R,\theta,\phi\}$ gives $d\mathbf{S} = R^2 \sin \theta d\theta d\phi \hat{e}_r $.

Comment: Well, OK, so how are you computing $\mathbf A\cdot \hat e_r$?

Comment: It should be $R^2 \sin u (R^2 \sin^3 u \cos^3 v + 2R \sin^2u \sin^2v + R \cos^2 u)$. Symmetry demands odd powers of  $cos(v)$ (or $sin(v)$) to vanish so we're left with $2R^3 \sin^3 u \sin^2 v + R^3 \sin u \cos^2 u$ as our integrand

Comment: I find it easier to do the dot product in cartesian coordinates — namely, $(x^2,2y,z)\cdot (x,y,z)/R = (x^3+2y^2+z^2)/R$ — and then convert to spherical coordinates. But I think we agree. And the integral comes out right.

Comment: Yes, that's (kinda) what I did in chat earlier. I wanted to try another way as well. Thanks for the help!